# PyGObject: Gio.File.copy_async() doesn't exist in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, programming, gtk3, pygi

According to [GIO Reference Manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-copy-async) `Gio.File` has a methode `copy_async`. In Ubuntu 12.04 I'm getting an `AttributeError` when I try to call this method.

What should I use instead to for asynchronous copying?

I could use `Gio.OutputStream.splice_async()` but that doesn't give me a progress callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference manual you are quoting is not for python. I'm aware, that with gobject introspection, no python manual is available anymore (only a [tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)), but this manual does not document the python mapped functionality. A lot of functions from C have not been made accessible from other languages.

One way you might want to go, if you do not require Gio, is simply using python built-in functions?

The `concurrent.futures` [module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) does things in an async way (backported [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures/)).
With that you should be able to do something like this:

```
import concurrent.futures
import shutil

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    executor.submit(shutil.copy, "test1.txt", "test1_new.txt").add_done_callback(
      process_result )
    executor.submit(shutil.copy, "test2.txt", "test2_new.txt").add_done_callback(
      process_result)
```

More about this version [here](http://www.beyondlinux.com/2012/02/07/the-concurrent-futures-module-in-python-3-2/) and [here](http://www.developer.com/lang/other/using-the-new-python-32-concurrent-programming-features.html).

Comment: I'd prefer GIO asynchronous functions but that doesn't seem to be possible with Python so I'll go with Python libs. `concurrent.futures` looks nice